# What happens if a thread in C tries to acquire a lock it already has?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking, mutex

So assuming 1 thread,
the thread acquires a lock via:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

then before unlocking, it again reaches a line that is:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
```

Will the pthread library block the advancement of the thread, or will it recognize that the thread already holds the lock, thus letting it pass?

Comment: Did it deadlock when you tried it or not?

Comment: Have you tried to [read some documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html)?

Comment: I already tried doing those things. But couldn't figure it out, so that's why I am asking here.

Comment: @RayToal trying is not the proper way to learn anything about C!!!

Comment: When you tried it, you could not figure out if it deadlocked or not?   Please show the code you used to test it.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala this question is not about C.  It's about the pthreads lib and OS.  A trial is appropriate.

Comment: @MartinJames a trial is not appropriate if the documentation says that in some cases the behaviour is undefined...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behaviour depends on the kind of the mutex. The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) says that recursive locking behaviour depends on the type of the lock

> If a thread attempts to relock a mutex that it has already locked, `pthread_mutex_lock()` shall behave as described in the Relock column of the following table.

With the Relock column saying that

- a mutex of type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_NORMAL` can deadlock
- a mutex of type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` shall return an error
- a mutex of type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_RECURSIVE` will work as a recursive lock, that you must then unlock as many times as you locked it
- a mutex of type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` will have **undefined behaviour**, which actually means that if on that platform the default lock is of any of the previous 3 types, it will behave characteristically as in the columns above, and if it is some other type then the behaviour will be undefined.

Thus there is especially no point in *testing* a `PTHREAD_MUTEX_DEFAULT` lock to find out what the behaviour is.

And the [Linux manuals `pthread_mutex_lock(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) rephrases with the following:

> If the mutex is already locked by the calling thread,
> the  behavior  of  pthread_mutex_lock  depends on the
> kind of the mutex. If the mutex is  of  the  *fast*
> kind, the calling thread is suspended until the mutex
> is unlocked, thus  effectively  causing  the  calling
> thread  to  deadlock.  If the mutex is of the *error
> checking* kind, pthread_mutex_lock  returns  immediately  with  the error code `EDEADLK`.  If the mutex is
> of the *recursive*  kind,  `pthread_mutex_lock`  succeeds  and  returns immediately, recording the number
> of times the calling thread has locked the mutex.  An
> equal  number of `pthread_mutex_unlock` operations must
> be performed before the mutex returns to the unlocked
> state.

In Linux according to the documentation, the default type is *fast*, but you cannot rely that to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX supports many different mutex types in several variants.  All use the same `pthread_mutex_t` type, so it is not possible to tell what `pthread_mutex_lock` does when re-locking a lock which has already been acquired by the current  thread.

Common behaviors include:

- A self-deadlock for a regular mutex (`pthread_mutex_lock` never returns).
- An error for an error-checking mutex (`pthread_mutex_lock` returns with an error code).
- The lock operation succeeds and one more unlock operation will be required before the lock becomes available to other threads for locking (a recursive mutex).

Mutex behavior can be selected when the mutex is created with `pthread_mutex_init` using attributes; see `pthread_mutexattr_init`.  Some systems also offer non-standard initializers like the standard `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER` one which create different variants.